# SQL: select original highest absolute value

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

```
WITH base AS (
    SELECT 'ID1' as id, 0 as foo
    UNION
    SELECT 'ID1' as id, -1 as foo
    UNION
    SELECT 'ID2' as id, 2 as foo
    UNION 
    SELECT 'ID2' as id, null as foo
    UNION 
    SELECT 'ID2' as id, -1 as foo
    UNION 
    SELECT 'ID2' as id, 1 as foo
)
select
    id
   ,MAX(CASE WHEN char_length(foo) > 0 THEN foo ELSE NULL END)
from base
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id ASC
```

This query returns 0 for the ID1 and 2 for the ID2.

What I'd like to have, is a SELECT expression that's going to return -1 for the ID1 and 2 for the ID2.

`MAX(ABS())` is almost what I want, but it returns `1` and not `-1`. I can't use JOIN and anything else, only a SELECT expression. Any ideas?

Comment: Where in your CTE do columns called `ID1` and `ID2` appear?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen There are no columns ID1 and ID2. These are the values of the `id` column. I changed the values so it's less confusing.

Comment: What happens if more than one ID has a max foo value?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm not sure what you mean. There's `GROUP BY` there, so nothing special happens. It just needs to do `MAX(ABS())` but return the original value, instead of the transformed one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to solve it:

```
select
    id
   ,MAX(ABS(foo)) * CASE WHEN ABS(MIN(foo)) > MAX(foo) THEN -1 ELSE 1 END As MaxAbs
from base
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Results:

```
id      MaxAbs
ID1     -1
ID2     2
```

Comment: This is too brilliant and underrated! I have been doing wrong my entire life. I used to make a sub query and left join to it.